# How to extract plateaus within clouded data (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, data-fitting

I am currently writing a program to detect edges in low-resolution binary images(In Matlab).

As the Hough-transform doesn't work well in pictures with a lot edges, I tried another approach

1. follow the boundary of the object region.
2. determine the slope/angle `a_i` of each boundary-pixel `i` (use a specific amount of neighbors to determine it).
3. determine the angle `(a_ort)_i` of each pixel `i` orthogonal to the calculated slope in 2).
4. follow in the direction of `(a_ort)_i` to determine the width `w_i` of the potential edge at position of pixel `i` (Let's assume I went in the right direction and not 180° to `(a_ort)_i`).

In the end I get two plots

a) A plot with boundary-pixel-index `i` on the x-axis and `(a_ort)_i` on the y-axis.

b) A plot with boundary-pixel-index `i` on the x-axis and `w_i` on the y-axis.

I want to detect where an edge might be. So for plot a) an edge might occur where there is a plateau for some range A on the x-axis (let's say with nearly-constant angle `a_A`) and then some very small plateau for range B (mostly only about 3-5 pixels) with angle `a_B`, that is followed by an area of range C and angle `a_C`.

As I 'drive around' the boundary with my imaginary car, the edge will translate to `w_A-w_C=180°` and
`w_B=w_A-90°` - sounds fair and simple. The same (but different!) holds for plot b), where w_A corresponds to a width `w_A`, which should be the same as range C with `w_C` (so `w_C=w_A`).
Range B will have some different value `w_B`. Now to the problematic part:
The plots I get are very clouded and difficult to read and extract data from. As the range B is mostly very small (only a few pixels) and the calculation of the corresponding angle and width `a_B` and `w_B` are mostly useless because of a very high error, I can disregard them entirely. I basically just have to find platea A and C and where there is some 'breaking' point. Actually, I would only need plot a) or b) to determine what I want (the pixel where the edge might be), but as the data is very bad with a lot of outliers, I want to include and use both of them.

Question: (TL:DR).

I have data from plot a) and data from plot b) where I want to find plateaus (lines of constant values) (disregard and filter everything else). In a) to determine values on the x-axis where there is a 'jump' from one plateau to another, whereas the plateaus differ in 180°. In b) I want to determine where there is a 'gap' between ONE plateau, which, ideally, should be as long as the two plateaus I am searching for in plot a).

Three pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The case of three "Plateaus" seems correspond to the case treated pages 14-16 in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

Below , copy (translated) from the above reference. I hope that will be helpful.

[image]

For a variant (global instead of piecewise regression) see in the referenced paper.

This is a very simple algorithm, not iterative. I suppose that it is easy to implement it into Matlab.

NOTE : If a1 and\or a2 are not real, or if one of them is outside the range [x1,xn] this means that the model made of three plateaus is not consistent with the data. In this case one have to try some other algorithms for less or more plateaus or for non horizontal segments, as shown in the referenced paper.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Sadly the amount of plateaus i get is higher and not constant (and even unknown)....